# GSON deserialize ArrayList<Long> to ArrayList<Double> in release version, not in debug version

Tags: android, json, serialization, arraylist, gson

I am using GSON to serialize my local stored information. Everything goes on well as I developed the function.

However, just before I release the formal version (export a release version of APK), the app crashed due to some class cast exception.

I have my local info declared as:

```
private class SavedInfo {
    public int appVersion; //Used for future update
    public int fileVersion;
    public ArrayList<Long> savedIDs;
    public SavedInfo() {
        savedIDs = new ArrayList<Long>();
    }
}
```

I found it crashed because GSON will deserialize my saved json string

```
{"savedIDs":[646,710],"fileVersion":2,"appVersion":220}
```

to ArrayList in memory, because once I call long id = savedIDs.get(index) I will get the "cannot cast Double to Long" exception.

My question is:

1. How to prevent GSON from doing this expected deserialization?
2. Why this issue only happens in release version, not in debug version?

By the way, I also disabled the pro-guard option on this class.